# Namespaces Scope

Tags: c#, namespaces

I have a *class* named `AuditLog` inside `Domain.AuditLog` namespace. I want to use `AuditLog` class inside another class with namespace `ApplicationServices.AuditLog`. like:

```
using Domain.AuditLog;
namespace ApplicationServices.AuditLog
{
    public interface IAuditLogService
    {
       List<AuditLog> GetAuditLogs();
    }
}
```

It says 'ApplicationServices.AuditLog' is a 'namespace' but is used like a 'type'. I know I can solve this using like:

```
namespace ApplicationServices.AuditLog
{
    using Domain.AuditLog;
    public interface IAuditLogService
   {
       List<AuditLog> GetAuditLogs();
   }
}
```

Is there another way of referencing `Domain.AuditLog` ?

Comment: Naming a class the same as its enclosing namespace leads to interesting namelookup issues. Hence the naming guidelines say you should avoid it.

Comment: Please read http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could help you:

```
using AL =  Domain.AuditLog.AuditLog;
namespace ApplicationServices.AuditLog
{
    public interface IAuditLogService
    {
       List<AL> GetAuditLogs();
    }
}
```